# Google spreadsheet convert values from thousands to millions

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have a spreadsheet full of data that each number represent thousand

For example: 1,745 represent 1,745,000

How can I convert each number (in the same cell) to represent millions so 1.745 will represent 1,745,000?

In MS Excel it can be done with special paste divide by 1000.
What's the equivalent in Google spreadsheet ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sheets' concept of thousands and millions is the same as Excel's (not everything else is however). Sheets does not, at the moment, have a direct equivalent of Excel's Paste Special with Operation.

If you want to convert each number representing thousands (in the same cell) to represent millions in Sheets then you will have to have each be divided by 1000. If you want this without helper cells you probably will need to write a script, though you could edit each cell individually or might export to Excel, use their inbuilt code and import back into Sheets, if required there.

Answer (score 0):

- if the number is `1,745` you **can't** change it **in the same cell** to million equivalent
- if the number is `1.745` you **can** change it **in the same cell** but  **only** "visually" to million equivalent with custom number formatting:

[image]

**note1:** its only visual change if you keep one eye shut
 
**note2:** this applies to the sheet with US locale. if you want to reverse it use some European locale